# Custom paginations in DataTables js

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, datatable, datatables

How can I add a custom pagination in [datatables.js](https://datatables.net/) as per the below illustration?

[image: the attached image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to add pagination is to add parameter 'paging' to your initial options, like that:

```
$('#your_table_id').dataTable( {
    "paging": true
});
```

Parameter 'paging' is set to `true` by default.

You can also add parameter `pagingType` and set it to `full_numbers`, like that:

```
$('#your_table_id').dataTable( {
    "paging": true,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
});
```

To display other pagination buttons (first, last) and add custom names to them you should use below code:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
  "pagingType": "full_numbers",
  "language": {
    "paginate": {
      "first":    "«",
      "previous": "‹",
      "next":     "›",
      "last":     "»"
    }
  }
});
```

and to add the style you can override some CSS rules like that:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
  /* other rules */
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
  /* other rules */
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled {
  border: 1px solid grey !important;
  /* other rules */
}
```

Unfortunately, it is ugly because you have to use the flag `!important`.

The other more difficult way is to write own plugin.

Comment: not at all, maybe u know how to add how to this symbol <<  1 2 3 4   >>  for changing page of table

Comment: @Rainbow Unicorn - please show me your HTML and JS code.

Comment: OK.. thanks.. so we have default pagination here and you wanna style the pagination..?

Comment: yes  i want pagination such on image https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOflu.png

Comment: @Rainbow Unicorn - I have edited my above answer to help you.. please review a new way and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211852/discussion-between-mario-boss-and-rainbow-unicorn).